# Problemas de visualización en el emulador oficial de Android

Tags: android-studio, avd, emulación

Uso `avd` el emulador de Android Studio  y me encuentro que a veces se muestra bien la app, pero cuando accedo a opciones, otras apps o cambio de ventana de windows, al volver solo me muestra una pantalla negra, si le doy tirar para atrás, parpadea.

No siempre pasa repitiendo la misma acción pero al rato acaba pasando.

En la sección errores de android-studio, muestra lo siguiente:

```
Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDeleteProgram:1103 error 0x501

glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x506 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
```

Mi equipo es nuevo: 
Intel i38300 con gráfica integrada intel HD630, 8GB de RAM, he testeado con la herramienta [GPUZ](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) para ver si era algo de los drivers y todo está correcto.

Que se tiene que configurar para que el emulador este estable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas o menos he conseguido estabilizar el renderizado del emulador, combinando las dos soluciones de [SOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595704/glteximage2d-got-err-pre-0x506-internal-0x1908-format-0x1908-type-0x1401)

`Administrador AVD -> editar -> Show advanced settings`

En la sección **Emulated performance**

- Graphics: Hardware - GLES 2.0
- Boot option: Cool boot

Luego con el emulador corriendo, abrir `Extended control` y pestaña `settings->Advanced`

- OpenGL ES rendered: SwiftShader
- OpenGL ES Api Level: Rendered Maxium (up to OpenGL ES 3.1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]